# making an index of words in texstudio

Tags: texstudio, indexing

so i want to make an index that shows where certain words appear in which pages in the output pdf

let's say I have a document that contains a certain amount of the word "avocado"
and at the end of the file, i want texstudio to show which page contains that word
something like

`avocado- 10, 15, 420, 500,`

is anything like that possible and if not, what's the closest I can do?
i did try using makeindex, printindex and all that and maybe that was it, but i can't seem to figure out how those work either

Comment: `makeindex` _is_ the solution. You could provide an example showing what you've tried and got by far.

Comment: unfortunately i can't present an exact example of what i did after someone other than me  tried to figure out how it worked, but i believe it was something along the lines of

```\begin{theindex}
 \index{avocado}
 \index{potato}
\end{theindex}```
and then also put a printindex call at the end of the main document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along the lines of:

```
% index2prob.tex SE 643379

\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\textheight}{0.5\textheight}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

Stuff about avocados.\index{avocardo}

\newpage

Different stuff about potatoes\index{potato} and avocardos.\index{avocardo}

Remember that the sequence of events should be:
\begin{itemize}
\item \verb!pdflatex index2prob! % compile the document
\item \verb!makeindex index2prob! % generate the index
\item \verb!pdflatex index2prob! % compile the document with its index
  \end{itemize}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that worked like a charm, thanks